# How to add parameters to a HTTP GET request in Android?

Tags: java, android, http-get

I have a HTTP GET request that I am attempting to send. I tried adding the parameters to this request by first creating a `BasicHttpParams` object and adding the parameters to that object, then calling `setParams( basicHttpParms )` on my `HttpGet` object. This method fails. But if I manually add my parameters to my URL (i.e. append `?param1=value1&param2=value2`) it succeeds.

I know I'm missing something here and any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: For a GET request, the second method is the correct way to add parameters. I expect the first approach is for POST methods.

Answer (score 227, accepted):

I use a List of NameValuePair and URLEncodedUtils to create the url string I want.

```
protected String addLocationToUrl(String url){
    if(!url.endsWith("?"))
        url += "?";

    List<NameValuePair> params = new LinkedList<NameValuePair>();

    if (lat != 0.0 && lon != 0.0){
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("lat", String.valueOf(lat)));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("lon", String.valueOf(lon)));
    }

    if (address != null && address.getPostalCode() != null)
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("postalCode", address.getPostalCode()));
    if (address != null && address.getCountryCode() != null)
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("country",address.getCountryCode()));

    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("user", agent.uniqueId));

    String paramString = URLEncodedUtils.format(params, "utf-8");

    url += paramString;
    return url;
}
```

Comment: I agree. I've gone back and changed this as this method makes sense for larger amounts of parameters. The first accepted answer still works fine, but can be confusing for large sets of parameters.

Comment: @Brian Griffey Thanks for good Solution. but i have little different format to pass parameter, Can anyone help me to pass this parameter..?   

How to pass parameter in this case?

data = '{
    "credential": {
        "accesToken": "668f514678c7e7f5e71a07044935d94c",
        "ACK": "cf3bb509623a8e8fc032a08098d9f7b3"
    },
   "restIn": {
        "userId": 4,
        "listId": 5613
    }
} ;

Comment: The other answer is much shorter and simpler for simple cases. It's not wrong, and worth considering.

Comment: List<NameValuePair>  is deprecated in android api level 22

Comment: @SimonMeier : use Uri.Builder() . See the answer below.

Comment: Not that it matters much, but why a LinkedList?

Comment: Please use Retrofit instead of manually building URL schemes.

Answer (score 99):

To build uri with get parameters, Uri.Builder provides a more effective way.

```
Uri uri = new Uri.Builder()
    .scheme("http")
    .authority("foo.com")
    .path("someservlet")
    .appendQueryParameter("param1", foo)
    .appendQueryParameter("param2", bar)
    .build();
```

Comment: Also cant handle file parameters

Comment: @bizso09 "file parameters" do you mean query and fragment? They are both settable by the builder.
Have a look at this for URI terminology, it helped me a lot http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/URI.html

Comment: how to remove query parameter? how to change value of existing query parameter?

Comment: there's a clear method http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/Uri.Builder.html#clearQuery(). to modify, assume that you have a list of queries, update the value in the list, clearQuery() and then call appendQueryParameter in the loop of the list. but why not create the new one every time on demand?

Answer (score 31):

As of [HttpComponents](https://hc.apache.org/) `4.2+` there is a new class [URIBuilder](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-4.2.x/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/client/utils/URIBuilder.html), which provides convenient way for generating URIs.

You can use either create URI directly from String URL:

```
List<NameValuePair> listOfParameters = ...;

URI uri = new URIBuilder("http://example.com:8080/path/to/resource?mandatoryParam=someValue")
    .addParameter("firstParam", firstVal)
    .addParameter("secondParam", secondVal)
    .addParameters(listOfParameters)
    .build();
```

Otherwise, you can specify all parameters explicitly:

```
URI uri = new URIBuilder()
    .setScheme("http")
    .setHost("example.com")
    .setPort(8080)
    .setPath("/path/to/resource")
    .addParameter("mandatoryParam", "someValue")
    .addParameter("firstParam", firstVal)
    .addParameter("secondParam", secondVal)
    .addParameters(listOfParameters)
    .build();
```

Once you have created `URI` object, then you just simply need to create `HttpGet` object and perform it:

```
//create GET request
HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(uri);
//perform request
httpClient.execute(httpGet ...//additional parameters, handle response etc.
```

Answer (score 29):

The method

```
setParams()
```

like

```
httpget.getParams().setParameter("http.socket.timeout", new Integer(5000));
```

only adds HttpProtocol parameters.

To execute the httpGet you should append your parameters to the url manually

```
HttpGet myGet = new HttpGet("http://foo.com/someservlet?param1=foo&param2=bar");
```

or use the post request
the difference between get and post requests are explained [here](http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/forms/methods.html), if you are interested

Comment: Thank you for your help. I thought there might be a more effective way of adding parameters to GET requests.

Answer (score 8):

```
List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("param1","value1");

String query = URLEncodedUtils.format(params, "utf-8");

URI url = URIUtils.createURI(scheme, userInfo, authority, port, path, query, fragment); //can be null
HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);
```

[URI javadoc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URI.html#URI%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20int,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29)

Note: `url = new URI(...)` is buggy

Answer (score 6):

```
    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();

    Uri.Builder builder = Uri.parse(url).buildUpon();

    for (String name : params.keySet()) {
        builder.appendQueryParameter(name, params.get(name).toString());
    }

    url = builder.build().toString();
    HttpGet request = new HttpGet(url);
    HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
    return EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity(), "UTF-8");
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have constant `URL` I recommend use simplified [http-request](https://github.com/jsunsoftware/http-request) built on apache http.

You can build your client as following:

```
private filan static HttpRequest<YourResponseType> httpRequest = 
                   HttpRequestBuilder.createGet(yourUri,YourResponseType)
                   .build();

public void send(){
    ResponseHendler<YourResponseType> rh = 
         httpRequest.execute(param1, value1, param2, value2);

    handler.ifSuccess(this::whenSuccess).otherwise(this::whenNotSuccess);
}

public void whenSuccess(ResponseHendler<YourResponseType> rh){
     rh.ifHasContent(content -> // your code);
}

public void whenSuccess(ResponseHendler<YourResponseType> rh){
   LOGGER.error("Status code: " + rh.getStatusCode() + ", Error msg: " + rh.getErrorText());
}
```

Note: There are many useful methods to manipulate your response.