# What does the ? mean in "format(List<? extends NameValuePair>"

Tags: java, urlencode, http-get, http-method, getmethod

I'm following the indications on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2959316/how-to-add-parameters-to-a-http-get-request-in-android) post to create a a parametrized URI for an Http GetMethod (http://some.domain/path?param1=value1&param2=value2) and I ran into a new issue.

I have this code:

```
List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
...
some code which does: params.add(new BasicNameValuePair(paramName, paramValue));
...
String paramString = URLEncodedUtils.format(params, "utf-8");
```

However, my Eclipse says that URLEncodeUtils.format does not accept type `List<NameValuePair>` but only `List<? extends NameValuePair>`.

I thought this may mean that only a subclass would be accepted (I see no sense in it, though, since NameValuePair is not abstract) but I also tried doing this with no luck:

```
class NameValuePairExtension extends NameValuePair{}
List<NameValuePairExtension> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePairExtension>();
```

What does this exactly mean?

EDIT:

Thanks for your quick replies.

A part from the theorical repsonses, I just found the "practical solution":
NameValuePair is an Interface, so it format connot work with it, and requires an implementation.

Therefore, the solution is to replace NameValuePair by a BasicNameValuePair, which implements the first one.

However, I still find this "extends" a bit confusing.

Comment: I think we've answered many of these Generics questions here on SO, no? :p

Comment: My appologises if this is the case. I tried searching through the posts, but I found nothing. Maybe the "?" made the search fail, and serching only for "extends" lead to lots of other issues

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Xxx<? extends Yyy>` means that `Xxx` has a generic type parameter that can be whatever you want while it implements interface `Yyy` (if `Yyy` is an interface) or extends class `Yyy` (if `Yyy` is a class).

Comment: Thanks for your Response!
I just posted a comment in Jon's Answer: I just realized that NameValuePair is an Interface, so the reason may be the lack of implementation, whether it is an extension or not.

Answer (score 2):

It means it's a list of *some type* which extends `NameValuePair` (or *is* `NameValuePair`) but we don't know what type, and we don't care.

This is a *wildcard* in Java generics. See the [Java Generics FAQ](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/TypeArguments.html#Wildcards) for more details.

EDIT: My guess is that you're using the wrong `NameValuePair` type. Please post the *exact* compilation error and it may become clearer...

Comment: Thanks for your comment. However, in this case none of these things worked: neither NameValuePair nor an extension.
However, I just realized that NameValuePair is an Interface, so this may be the reason on the failure

Comment: @Carles: Are you sure you've got the right `NameValuePair` type?

Comment: Thanks for the tip. However, I already found the exact problem and edited the initial question to include it

Comment: @Carles: `format` should be absolutely fine with a `List<NameValuePair>`. I don't think the problem is where you think it is...