# HttpPost URI is not full

Tags: android, uri, http-post

I want to get **json** info from the link:
**http://android.forum-example.org/?a=1&b=2&c=3**

but **Log.v** tells me that after *request.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(qparams));*
my **URI** is: **http://android.forum-example.org/?**

Where is my mistake?

**code:**

```
try {
    HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost request = new HttpPost("http://android.forum-example.org/?");
    List<NameValuePair> qparams = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(3);
    qparams.add(new BasicNameValuePair("a", "1"));
    qparams.add(new BasicNameValuePair("b", "2"));
    qparams.add(new BasicNameValuePair("c", "3"));
    request.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(qparams));
    Log.v("URI:", request.getURI().toString());
    HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(request);
    } catch (IOException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
```

Comment: 11-06 17:21:03.758: V/URI:(13235): http://android.forum-example.org/?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `HttpGet` instead of `HttpPost`:

```
try {
    HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpGet request = new HttpGet("http://android.forum-example.org/?a=1&b=2&c=3");
    Log.v("URI:", request.getURI().toString());
    HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(request);
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to make a `POST` request.. but the url is of type `GET` request

look here : [How to add parameters to a HTTP GET request in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2959316/how-to-add-parameters-to-a-http-get-request-in-android)

Comment: and if we want POST ?, is it possible ?