# Adding parameter to HttpPost on Apache's httpclient

Tags: java, apache, parameters, get, httpclient

I am trying to set some Http parameters in the HttpPost object.

```
HttpPost post=new HttpPost(url);
HttpParams params=new BasicHttpParams();
params.setParameter("param", "value");
post.setParams(params);
HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
```

It looks like the parameter is not set at all. Do you have any idea why this is happening?

Thank you

Comment: `HttpPost get`! is it meant to be a POST or a GET?

Comment: You say **`HttpGet`** in the description and title but then your code says **`HttpPost`**. I just edited it to be correct

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
List<NameValuePair> nvps = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair("param", "value"));
httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nvps, HTTP.UTF_8));
httpClient.execute(httpPost);
```

Comment: this question is asked for http get request. you cannot setEntity for a http get request

Comment: Should be using LinkedList instead of ArrayList

Comment: @Benedictus, why?

Comment: ArrayList's are good for holding non-changing data, and quick indexing. But are slow and space-consuming when you add or remove members. The LinkedList structure is more suitable in this scenario.

Answer (score 26):

For those who hopes to find the answer using HttpGet, here's one (from https://stackoverflow.com/a/4660576/330867) :

```
StringBuilder requestUrl = new StringBuilder("your_url");

String querystring = URLEncodedUtils.format(params, "utf-8");
requestUrl.append("?");
requestUrl.append(querystring);

HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpGet get = new HttpGet(requestUrl.toString());
```

**NOTE**: This doesn't take in consideration the state of `your_url` : if there is already some parameters, if it already contains a "?", etc. I assume you know how to code/search and will adapt regarding your case.

Comment: DefaultHttpClient is deprecated.