# Issue while downloading file with special character

Tags: android, download, special-characters

I am facing some issue while downloading files from android application. The application is used for downloading pdf, image and video files from server for off-line use. If the file name contain any special character (like é,à,î....) the file is not downloading. From android we are downloading the file using the URL. And the same URL can access from browser. All other files are downloading perfectly. Please advise us to resolve this issue.

Comment: show the code your using to download the files.

Comment: The issue is with URL encoding. Check this SO post.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10219299/illegal-characters-in-url-for-httpget-in-android-get-double-encoded and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3286067/url-encoding-in-android