# How can i parse a TwitterFeed (JSON) to a custom listview?

Tags: java, android, json, listview, twitter

I have got a code from a tutorial How to parse JSON data into a Custom Listview

Here is the code from the tutorial with a couple of modifications:

```java
public class TwitterParseHandler extends Activity {
ArrayList<TwitterFeed> arrayOfWebData = new ArrayList<TwitterFeed>();

class TwitterFeed {
    public String text;
    public String created_at;
}

FancyAdapter aa=null;

static ArrayList<String> resultRow;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    try
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_twitter_parse_handler);
        String result = "";

        try
        {
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.json?include_entities=true&include_rts=true&screen_name=3FMNu&count=20&exclude_replies=True");
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            InputStream webs = entity.getContent();

            try
            {
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(webs, "iso-8859-1"),8);
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                String line = null;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    sb.append(line + "/n");
                }

                webs.close();
                result=sb.toString();
            }catch(Exception e){
                Log.e("log_tag", "Error in converting result "+e.toString());
            }
        }catch(Exception e){
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection "+e.toString());
        }

        try
        {
            JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);
            for (int i=0;i<jArray.length();i++)
            {
                JSONObject json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                TwitterFeed resultRow = new TwitterFeed();
                resultRow.text = json_data.getString("text");
                resultRow.created_at = json_data.getString("created_at");

                arrayOfWebData.add(resultRow);
            }
        }catch(JSONException e){
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error in parsing data "+e.toString());
        }

        ListView myListView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);

        aa=new FancyAdapter();

        myListView.setAdapter(aa);
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        Log.e("ERROR", "ERROR IN CODE: "+e.toString());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

class FancyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<TwitterFeed> {
    FancyAdapter() {
        super(TwitterParseHandler.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, arrayOfWebData);
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder;

        if (convertView==null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater=getLayoutInflater();
            convertView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.twitterlist, null);

            holder=new ViewHolder(convertView);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        }
        else
        {
            holder=(ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
        }
        holder.populateFrom(arrayOfWebData.get(position));

        return(convertView);
    }
}

class ViewHolder {
    public TextView name=null;
    public TextView birthday=null;

    ViewHolder(View row) {
        name=(TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.TwitterText);
        birthday=(TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.TwitterDatum);
    }

    void populateFrom(TwitterFeed r) {
        name.setText(r.text);
        birthday.setText(r.created_at);
    }
}
}
```

I have replaced the JSON from the tutorial (that was working fine) with my twitterfeed: https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.json?include_entities=true&include_rts=true&screen_name=3FMNu&count=20&exclude_replies=True

and changed the attributes from `name` and `birthday` to `text` and `created_at`, now when I debug it I get the following error:

```js
08-04 12:36:40.539: E/log_tag(4599): Error in parsing data org.json.JSON
Exception: Value 
{ "error": "This method requires a GET.",
  "request":"\/1\/statuses\/user_timeline.json?include_entities=true&include_rts=true&screen_name=3FMNu&count=20&exclude_replies=True"
} of type org.json.JSONObject cannot be converted to JSONArray
```

Why does this happen and how do I fix it?

Comment: Have you tried `httpget`? `HttpGet request = new HttpGet("twitter url");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.json);
```

with parameters:

```
List<NameValuePair> params = new LinkedList<NameValuePair>();
params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("include_entities", true));
...
```

Try also [How to add parameters to a HTTP GET request in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2959316/how-to-add-parameters-to-a-http-get-request-in-android)

Comment: Hey thanks!, sorry for the late response was on vacation, yes it worked HttpGet was the problem, the parameters were not needed.

Comment: No problem, I'm glad that was helpful for you ;)