# Android HTTP GET parameters

Tags: android, apache, http, get, query-string

I'm using the apache http library and need to know how to add a parameter to an HTTP GET request. I've looked over [How to add parameters to a HTTP GET request in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2959316/how-to-add-parameters-to-a-http-get-request-in-android) but the accepted answer for that adds parameters to an HTTP POST. This is my code so far but it is not working.

```
HttpGet get = new HttpGet("https://server.com/stuff");
List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("count", "5"));
HttpParams p = get.getParams();
p.setParameter("length", "5");
get.setParams(p);
```

Comment: Please explain how it is not working - does it not compile, crash, or just not return the expected results?

Comment: Adding a get parameter is trivial. You can just make it `new HttpGet("https://server.com/stuff?id=" + 123);` for example

Comment: use "http://server.com/stuff" + URLEncodedUtils.format(nameValuePairs, "utf-8"); HttpParams is for http parameters, which are protocol related.

Comment: the server acts as if it is not receiving a parameter at all when i use the above method. I'll try njzk2's answer

Answer (score 8, accepted):

unlike POST, GET sends the parameters under the url like this:

```
http://myurl.com?variable1=value&variable2=value2
```

Where: the parameters area start from the question mark and on so the *variable1* is the first param and it has "*value*" value...

See [here](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_httpmethods.asp) for more informations.

So what you need to do is just build an url that contains also these parameters according to server needs.

**EDIT:**

In your case :

```
HttpGet get = new HttpGet("https://server.com/stuff?count=5&length=5");
...
```

Where: count=5 and length=5 are the parameters and the "?" mark is the beginning of the parameters definition...
I hope that helps.

Comment: This worked, I just wish there was an easier way than building a string.

Comment: Well you could design a helper method to do that.. and using a list of value and pair object you could generate the url... and also encode it by your needs...

Answer (score 14):

```
String url = "https://server.com/stuff"
List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(1);
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("count", "5"));
HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
String paramsString = URLEncodedUtils.format(nameValuePairs, "UTF-8");
HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url + "?" + paramsString);
HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
```

**EDIT:** Since Android SDK v22, the type `NameValuePair` is deprecated. I recommend using [Volley](https://developer.android.com/training/volley/index.html), an HTTP library that makes networking for Android apps easier and most importantly, faster.