# Error HTTP 422 GET in Android

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to perform a GET request to the server that returns me a JSON file. But I am getting an error in the HTTP statusLine / 422. Anyone know why. Below I show how I'm doing

```
public void testConverteArquivoJsonEmObjetoJava() {

    DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpGet get = new HttpGet(
            "http://safe-sea-4024.ppooiheroku4554566adffasdfasdfalaqwerpcp.com/crimes/mobilelist");

    get.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
    get.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");

    get.getParams()
            .setParameter("token",
                    "0V1AYFK12SeCZHYgXbNMew==$tRqPNplipDwtbD0vxWv6GPJIT6Yk5abwca3IJ88888a6JhMs=");

    HttpResponse httpResponse;
    try {
        httpResponse = httpClient.execute(get);
        String jsonDeResposta = EntityUtils.toString(httpResponse
                .getEntity());

        System.out.println();

    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: HTTP status code indicates an unprocessable entity, which normally means that the data you're supplying is not recognized by the server. You should consult the API documentation to verify what data is required for the call. Also, is that your real token you included in the question?

Comment: Can you paste the exception trace.

Comment: Yes, this token is valid. However the server test.

Comment: Not the error. I just get a satusLine HTTP/1.1 422 and `httpResponse.getEntity()` is null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually you do not specify a `Content-Type` header with a `GET` request.  This header tells the server how to interpret the entity includes in the message.  It is possible that the server side is expecting a JSON entity even though `GET` cannot include a body.  Try removing the `Content-Type` header.

I tried the URL that you cleverly changed and got it to work fine.  However, I did get a 422 when I specified a different token query parameter.  Being that the status line is missing a phrase, I would assume that the Ruby application is generating it.

Comment: You can test with this URL [link]http://safe-sea-4024.herokuapp.com/crimes/mobilelist
I removed the header and continues with error. Do you think the problem is on the server Ruby?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve the problem. I was passing the parameter so wrong. According to this post [blog]:[How to add parameters to a HTTP GET request in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2959316/how-to-add-parameters-to-a-http-get-request-in-android) "link". This method is used to that I kind of POST request

this method is correct

```
 public void testConverteArquivoJsonEmObjetoJava() {
    List<NameValuePair> params = new LinkedList<NameValuePair>();

    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("token","0V1AYFK12SeCZHYgXbNMew==$="));

    String paramString = URLEncodedUtils.format(params, "utf-8");

    DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpGet get = new HttpGet(
            "http://safep.com/crimes/mobilelist" + "?"
                    + paramString);
    HttpResponse httpResponse;
    try {

        httpResponse = httpClient.execute(get);
        String jsonDeResposta = EntityUtils.toString(httpResponse
                .getEntity());

        System.out.println();

    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}`
```