# How to add NameValuePairs for a HttpGet request in android

Tags: android, http-get

**In the line :** `httpget.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));`

**I am getting error as:** `The method setEntity(UrlEncodedFormEntity) is undefined for the type HttpGet`

---

### CODE:

```
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        // Add the header data for the request
        List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("phonenumber","12345"));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("authtoken", "12345"));
        HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(url);
        httpget.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

        // Execute HTTP Post Request
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpget);
```

Comment: Check : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2959316/how-to-add-parameters-to-a-http-get-request-in-android

Answer (score 6):

GET request does not have a body that could contain an entity, the parameters you want to include should be built-in into the URL itself.

A clean way to do this is to use `URIBuilder`:

```
URIBuilder builder = new URIBuilder();
builder.setScheme("http").setHost(host).setPort(port).setPath(yourpath)
.setParameter("parts", "all")
.setParameter("action", "finish");
```

Answer (score 3):

Try to use BasicNameValuePair List add params and get formmated string from URLEncodedUtils which concat to url :

```
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
List<BasicNameValuePair> params = new LinkedList<BasicNameValuePair>();
params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("phonenumber", "12345"));
params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("authtoken", "12345"));
HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(url+"?"+URLEncodedUtils.format(params, "utf-8"));
HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpget);
```

Answer (score 0):

try like this way,

I use a List of NameValuePair and URLEncodedUtils to create the url string I want.

```
protected String addLocationToUrl(String url){
    if(!url.endsWith("?"))
        url += "?";

    List<BasicNameValuePair> params = new LinkedList<BasicNameValuePair>();

    if (lat != 0.0 && lon != 0.0){
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("lat", String.valueOf(lat)));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("lon", String.valueOf(lon)));
    }

    if (address != null && address.getPostalCode() != null)
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("postalCode", address.getPostalCode()));
    if (address != null && address.getCountryCode() != null)
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("country",address.getCountryCode()));

    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("user", agent.uniqueId));

    String paramString = URLEncodedUtils.format(params, "utf-8");

    url += paramString;
    return url;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the reason is because setEntity method is belongs to HttpPost. Not HttpGet you can correct your error simply by changing HttpGet to HttpPost ..

```
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);
        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
```

also in your php code change all `$_GET["your key"];` methods to `$_POST["your key"];`