# Regex Conversion From Javascript to Java

Tags: java, javascript, regex

I am working on client-server application in java, (converting some code from java-script). I am struck. In java i am sending values to server by embedding in namevaluepairs. But after putting values i am getting empty json in java, which is working in javascript (values sending via GET using web forms ).

Here it javascript form statement:

```
<input type="text" name="criteria" value= 'Email=="wei.wang_zh@pcstars.com"'>
```

and here is java namevaluepair statement in which i am getting issue:

```
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("criteria", "'Email==\"wei.wang_zh@pcstars.com\"'"));
```

I have tried to put string in a String data type, which is also not working. Here it is

```
String val="wei.wang_zh@pcstars.com";
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("criteria", "'Email==\""+val+"\"'"));
```

Please let me know what mistake i'm doing in both cases. Thanks

Comment: if you are passing those name value pair as part of a GET request,you need to url encode the value first! Also how are you sending the GET request.Please show us the complete code

Comment: Anirudha, Dear there is no issue in the server sending part. I am getting results if i use simple "Email=---" (email without special characters) but the zoho server has 'Email=="wei.wang_zh@pcstars.com"' sent me method (If i include special characters in email)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how you are sending the params to server but I think answer provided in following link may help

https://stackoverflow.com/a/4660576/4600335

```
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("criteria", "'Email==\"wei.wang_zh@pcstars.com\"'"));

String paramString = URLEncodedUtils.format(nameValuePairs, "utf-8");

url += paramString;
```